# How to add entity to multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, multiple-tables, ef4-code-only

I have 2 tables in my DB: `Students` and `StudentsHistory`. The idea is that every change in the `Students` table must create a new record in the `StudentsHistory` table (e.g. when I edit a student, 2 operations must be performed: UPDATE on Students and INSERT on StudentsHistory).

How can I do this with Entity Framework 4.1 Code-First **without** creating 2 classes and having them mapped? I want to have only `Student` class and somehow tell EF to save the Student object to 2 tables.

Anyone can help?

PS It should be done in code, not using SQL triggers or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ladislav said, you cannot map 2 tables to one entity. You may want to think about creating an [audit](http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/) for student history.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You must create two classes, map them and handle creation in your business logic. The auto magic you are looking for can be performed only by database triggers.

Comment: Even though those tables have identical columns? StudentsHistory has 1 extra column: foreign key to Students.